# Should I be using a DTO when passing data from my server to clients?

Tags: c#, json, dto

I feel like I've gone and over-complicated my design by using DTOs, but I'm looking for a second opinion.

My structure is:

- User <- One-to-Many -> Playlist <- One-to-Many -> PlaylistItem <- One-to-One -> Video

As such, a PlaylistItem domain object looks like:

```
public class PlaylistItem
{
    public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Playlist Playlist { get; set; }
    public virtual int Sequence { get; set; }
    public virtual string Title { get; set; }
    public virtual Video Video { get; set; }

    //  Not written to the database. Used for client to tell who is who after a save.
    public virtual string Cid { get; set; }
}
```

and a PlaylistItem DTO looks like:

```
[DataContract]
public class PlaylistItemDto
{
    [DataMember(Name = "playlistId")]
    public Guid PlaylistId { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "id")]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "sequence")]
    public int Sequence { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "title")]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "video")]
    public VideoDto Video { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "cid")]
    public string Cid { get; set; }
}
```

The only change is that I have broken the circular-referential structure by replacing the Playlist reference with a PlaylistId.

The default JSON serializer in C# .NET MVC was unable to handle circular structures. I've since updated to using the JSON.NET serializer which is capable of handling circular structures. I'm now re-evaluating why I even need my DTO.

Are there any benefits of a DTO that I should be aware of / considering here? Is it bad practice to JSONize a circular reference and send it across the wire?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSON, being a hierarchical format, is going to work best when representing data in a hierarchical fashion. JSON isn't a node graph, so trying to serialize graph-like data is going to prove difficult, I think. I think your solution of converting an object (`Playlist`) to a form of "reference" (`PlaylistId`) is the correct one. The code receiving and processing this JSON can reconstruct the circular reference, if necessary, since you have your "foreign key" (`PlaylistId`) in place.

Most of the time I would rather have an extra DTO than none at all. DTOs insulate you from change--in this case, insulate your *API* from change. `PlaylistId` is unlikely to change its schema in the future, but the actual `Playlist` might.

Answer (score 2):

> Are there any benefits of a DTO that I should be aware of / considering here?

Design. THis is a public API and you want to make sure it is sable, while the internal objects are / can change without a lot of review. Changes in data types are a lot more problematic if this is an "out of the server" style interface and you do not want to force API updates (client updates) every time you do a minor change.

As such, having API level definition objects (DTO) separately defined helps with this part of not changing a public interface.